# ColdFusion get client side URL

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting, coldfusion-11

I am using `URL rewriter` and I want to get `client side URL`. I tried dumping `CGI` but there was no information about this.

If the requested URL is : `www.test.com/test/testing-data`

And after rewriting it became: `www.test.com/test.cfm?urlData=testing-data`

Now, I want to get : `/test/testing-data`.

I can get this in **JS** by using `window.location.pathname`.

**My question is:** How can we get the same using `ColdFusion`? Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that URL rewriting happens *before* the request is forwarded to the ColdFusion App engine. You can try dumping out *gethttprequestdata()* and see if the host header matches the original - but I doubt it as the CGI scope has this data parsed.

Your best bet will be to change the rewrite rule to include a URL param. So in your example: `test.cfm?urlData=testing-data` could now be `test.cfm?urldata=testing-data&originalpath=/test/test-data` - or the URLEncoded equivilant of that.

It occurs to me that the variable urlData already contains the data you need to reconstruct the path. Can't you just do something like:

```
<cfset variables.mypath = '/test/' & url.urlData>
```

That seems like what you want no?

Comment: Reconstructing the path can be done at page level but I want it in template.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your end game then. you want it "in template" - means what exactly? If it's in a variable it's in a variable - cgi, url, form, variables ...what's the difference?

Comment: Does the `X-REWRITE-URL` header contain what you're after?

Comment: Adam - doesn't the population of that var depend on the rewrite engine being used? I thought that one came from the URLREWRITE module (apache).

Comment: Yes it does. It's up to the webserver to provide the initially requested resource to the application server. The forwarded URI is usually set in the HTTP headers and depends on the rewrite engine in use.

Comment: So it would show up in the header if you used gethttprequestdata() then - that would give him what he wants - assuming it is set.